# NOW in Postgresql - show date only

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I need to use `NOW()` in Postgres 11.5 and need to get the date like below:

```
2019-10-07
```

aka YYYY-MM-DD style. How do I do this? Just using `NOW()` alone gives me a huge string with time and everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE
```

or do an explicit cast

```
SELECT now()::date
```